# Disable all prints except the ones done in the called function

Tags: python, printing, decorator

I have a function in which I call some functions from the same module or some other modules :

```
from __future__ import print_function

def func():
    print("Inside func")

def my_func():
    print("Starting inside my_func ")
    func()
    print("In my_func")
    func()
```

Executing `my_func` outputs this:

```
Starting inside my_func
Inside func
In my_func
Inside func
```

But I would only want to see

```
Starting inside my_func
In my_func
```

So, I want to disable all the prints except for the ones made
directly in the function `my_func()`. This may include the recursive calls to the function. So doing something with the stack level won't work.

I can think of doing this

```
def func():
    print("Inside func")

def my_print(*args):
    print(*args)

def my_func():
    global my_print, print
    my_print("Starting inside my_func ")
    print = functools.partial(print, file=open(os.devnull, 'w'))
    func()
    print = functools.partial(print, file=sys.stdout)
    my_print("In my_func")
    print = functools.partial(print, file=open(os.devnull, 'w'))
    func()
    print = functools.partial(print, file=sys.stdout)
```

But this involves modifying the function code and seems a bit hacky. I would ideally want to do this using a decorator, without the need to modify the function code.

The most natural way would be to find prints not called in `my_func` and make them output to `os.devnull` in the wrapper. But I can't find how to do that. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does my answer solve your problem? If so, can you accept the answer? If not, please let me know which issues this answer does not address.

Comment: Hi, thanks. It works. Was waiting if more people answered.

Comment: No problem. You can always accept a new answer if you find it to be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save the reference to the `print` function in a variable `orig_print` and override `print` with a function that does nothing, and then use a decorator on the function you want to allow printing to rename all calls to `print` to `orig_print` with a `ast.NodeTransformer` subclass:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import inspect
import ast
from textwrap import dedent

orig_print = print
print = lambda *args, **kwargs: None

class EnablePrint(ast.NodeTransformer):
    # remove the enable_print decorator from the decorator list so the transformed
    # function won't be re-decorated when executed
    def visit_FunctionDef(self, node):
        node.decorator_list = [
            decorator for decorator in node.decorator_list
            if not isinstance(decorator, ast.Name) or decorator.id != 'enable_print'
        ]
        self.generic_visit(node)
        return node

    def visit_Call(self, node):
        if node.func.id == 'print':
            node.func.id = 'orig_print'
        return node

def enable_print(func):
    node = ast.parse(dedent(inspect.getsource(func)))
    EnablePrint().visit(node)
    scope = {}
    exec(compile(node, inspect.getfile(func), 'exec'), func.__globals__, scope)
    return scope[func.__name__]
```

so that:

```
def func():
    print("Inside func")

@enable_print
def my_func():
    print("Starting inside my_func ")
    func()
    print("In my_func")
    func()

my_func()
```

would output:

```
Starting inside my_func 
In my_func
```

Answer (score 0):

@blhsing has given a nice approach. But I ended up solving my issue using `pprint.pprint` in my function and disabling the outputs of `print`. This works because `pprint` uses more low level `stream.write("...")` instead of bootstrapping on `print`. The code:

```
def disable_prints(f):
    @functools.wraps(f)
    def decorated(*args, **kwargs):
        global print
        # Disable all calls made to print(...) by relacing stdout with devnull
        print = functools.partial(print, file=open(os.devnull, 'w'))
        f_returns = f(*args, **kwargs)
        # Restore back
        print = functools.partial(print, file=sys.stdout)
        return f_returns
    return decorated
```

so that:

```
def func():
    print("Inside func")

@disable_prints
def my_func():
    pprint("Starting inside my_func")
    func()
    pprint("In my_func")
    func()

my_func()
```

would output:

```
Starting inside my_func 
In my_func
```

Comment: This answer does not actually answer the question because it isn't actually using `print` in the decorated function, where `print` is still disabled, which does not meet your goal of "I want to disable all the prints except for the ones made in the function `my_func()`". Also, overriding `print` globally during a function call is not thread-safe, so if a thread calling the decorated function needs to run concurrently, printing would be re-enabled by other threads when they are not inside this function when a thread inside this function needs `print` disabled.

Comment: Also, `pprint` behaves quite differently from `print`. Unlike `print`, `pprint` always prints the output of the `__repr__` method of a given object, so `pprint('hi')` would output `'hi'` rather than `hi`, and is therefore not a good replacement for `print` for producing user-friendly output.

Comment: Points taken. Thanks. Leaving the ans, as seems easier to understand.